# lisp clos accessor problems

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, clos

I can't use the clos accessor functions when the class is in a list.

Say I have class a:

```
(defclass a ()
  ((a :accessor a
      :initarg :a)))
```

And I make 2 instances:

```
(defparameter b (make-instance 'a :a 1))
(defparameter c (make-instance 'a :a 2))
```

and then if I wanted to create a function that would get the a value for each of the instances while in a list i would do

```
(defun get-a (lst)
  (mapcar #'a lst))
```

and call it with

```
(get-a '(b c))
```

but I do that I get an error:

```
There is no applicable method for the generic function
  #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION A (1)>
when called with arguments
  (B).
    [Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]
```

And it also happens if instead of calling the accessor directly with mapcar, I call a function which contains the accessor. Also I've tried using loops and other things instead of mapcar.

Thanks

Comment: `(get-a (list b c))`, not `(get-a '(b c))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read the error, you get the explanation.

```
There is no applicable method for the generic function
  #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION A (1)>
when called with arguments
  (B).
```

So you got a call, which is similar to `(a 'b)`. But `b` is a symbol, not a CLOS instance.

`(b c)` is a list of two symbols. You probably wanted to create a list of two CLOS instances. Use `LIST` to create a list with evaluated arguments.